# Add and display the column values in single column in Google stacked chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am create a stacked graph using **google chart**.

[image]

Here I have 2 columns (one is blue and other is red). In each I displayed the value.

My code is:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        }, 2, {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 2,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        }]);
```

But I have to display the total value (blue+red).

That is my graph should look like this:

[image]

How can I do this?  Any help is really appreciable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a function to `calc` and lose the `sourceColumn`.
Something like this should work...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, {
    calc: getRowTotal,
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
}]);

function getRowTotal(dataView, row) {
    var val1;
    var val2;

    val1 = dataView.getValue(row, 1) || 0;
    val2 = dataView.getValue(row, 2) || 0;

    return val1 + val2;      
}
```

Comment: see [`setColumns`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns) for more info...

Comment: change  `type: "number",`  and  `return dataView.getValue(row, 1) + dataView.getValue(row, 2);` . Then it works